# Examples of "difficult" integrals with are easier to solve with a series?

Tags: calculus, integration, sequences-and-series, definite-integrals

Yesterday someone posted an extremely elegant solution to a seemingly bizarre series where the integral:

$$\int_{0}^{1} x^{m}\ dx =  \frac{1}{m + 1}$$

was utilized.

Oftentimes one will also interchange the summation from inside the integral to the outside in the case of uniformly convergent series.

Are there situations where an otherwise complicated looking integral has a "trivial" solution as a series?

Comment: I suppose that you are referring to [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/197604). (Which was not posted yesterday, but the last activity in that thread was, indeed, yesterday; which is why the question was bumped.)

Comment: You may also refer to one of [my answers](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/810669/123277).

Comment: Yes, these are precisely the sort of answers I was looking for!

Answer (score 7):

The following double integral is an example.

$$\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}\frac{1}{1-xy}\,dx\,dy=\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(xy)^{k-1}\,dx\,dy\\=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}(xy)^{k-1}\,dx\,dy=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{1}x^{k-1}\,dx\int_{0}^{1}y^{k-1}\,dy=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac1{k^2}=\frac{\pi^2}{6}$$

Comment: This is from Noam Elkies' paper, found here at http://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0101168v5.pdf, in case you need context.

Comment: I haven't taken vector analysis yet so my understanding of two variable integrals is very superficial, mostly to the extent that I have had to use them on my physics courses! If I understand correctly, there is some generalization of uniform convergence to n-dimensions which allows you to change the orders of integration and limits with this double integral.

Comment: @Mathguy:  Thanks for the reference.

Comment: @user30562: Each summand is non-negative and the series converges monotonically which justifies the switch.  In general we have bounded convergence, monotone and dominated convergence theorems to work with.

Answer (score 2):

In statistical physics, integrals of the form $\int_0^\infty dx\, {x^n}(e^{x}\pm 1)^{-1}$ are common, and the standard approach is to expand the reciprocal in powers of $e^{-x}$:
\begin{align}
\int_0^\infty dx\, \frac{x^n}{e^{x}\pm 1} 
&= \int_0^\infty dx\, \frac{x^n e^{-x}}{1\pm e^x}\\
&= \int_0^\infty dx\, x^n \sum_{k=0}^\infty (\mp 1)^k e^{-(k+1)x}\\
&= \sum_{k=0}^\infty (\mp 1)^k \int_0^\infty dx\, x^n e^{-(k+1)x}\\
&= \sum_{k=0}^\infty (\mp 1)^k \frac{n!}{(k+1)^{n+1}} = \left\{\array{n!\,\eta(n+1)\\ n!\, \zeta(n+1)}\right\}
\end{align}
where $\eta(n)$ and $\zeta(n)$ are the Dirichlet eta and Riemann zeta functions respectively. (Note that such integrals are really particular cases of the polylogarithm.)

Answer (score 1):

Here's an integral I saw on this [AoPS thread](http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Forum/viewtopic.php?f=296&t=542624) a while ago: $\displaystyle\int_{1}^{\infty}\left(\ln\left(1-\dfrac{1}{x}\right)\right)^2\,dx$

[WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate%20ln%281-1%2Fx%29%5E2%20from%20x%20%3D%201%20to%20infinity) tells us the answer is $\dfrac{\pi^2}{3}$, which should remind you of $\zeta(2) = \displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{n^2} = \dfrac{\pi^2}{6}$.

Indeed, using an infinite series is the way to go. Specifically, this one:  $\displaystyle\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}ny^{n} = \dfrac{y}{(1-y)^2}$.

Of course, evaluating that integral required a few more tricks. See that thread for a few solutions.

Comment: And how can one find the even zeta values remaining in the series framework?